# PHP Regex to remove HTML-Tags inside <pre></pre> code blocks

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, pre

I have a tricky string of HTML code that includes several pre tags that inside them include code (say, python), and that are also decorated by HTML tags that should be removed.

For example:

```
Some text.
<pre>
a = 5 <br/>
b = 3
</pre>
More text
<pre>
a2 = "<a href='something'>text</a>"
b = 3
</pre>
final text
```

I would like to clean out all the HTML tags (these are likely to be basic tags, br, em, div, a, etc.). I do not need to parse the HTML, I know that [regex cannot parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

```
Some text.
<pre>
a = 5
b = 3
</pre>
More text
<pre>
a2 = "text"
b = 3
</pre>
final text
```

I'd like to do this using PHP (with something like `preg_replace`). For example:

```
$html = "<html><head></head><body><div><pre class=\"some-css-class\">
         <p><strong>
         some_code = 1
         </p></strong>
         </pre></div></body>"; // Compacting things here, for brevity

$newHTML = preg_replace("/(.*?)<pre[^<>]*>(.*?)<\/pre>(.*)/Us", "$1".strip_tags("$2", '<p><a><strong>')."$3", $html);
echo $newHTML;
```

This example code obviously doesn't since: (1) it would work for only one pre tag, and (2) the code `strip_tags("$2", '<p><a><strong>')` would obviously not work, since it doesn't do the processing of the string in the right location (it would just return "$2" instead of getting the text and manipulating it properly).

Any suggestions on how this could be done in PHP? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `preg_replace_callback` and call `strip_tags` in callback body:

```
preg_replace_callback('~(<pre[^>]*>)([\s\S]*?)(</pre>)~',
function ($m) { return $m[1] . strip_tags($m[2], ['p', 'b', 'strong']) . $m[3]; },
$s);
```

```
Some text.
<pre>
a = 5
b = 3
</pre>
More text
<pre>
a2 = "text"
b = 3
</pre>
final text
```

Note that above `strip_tags` strips all tags except `p`, `b` and `strong`.

**RegEx Details:**

- `(<pre[^>]*>)`: Match `<pre...>` and capture in group #1
- `([\s\S]*?)`: Match 0 or or more of any character including newline (lazy), capture this in group $2. `[\s\S]` matches any character including newline.
- `(</pre>)`: Match `</pre>` and capture in group #3

Comment: Amazing! Could you please help explain the regex in the code?

Comment: Sure, let me add it in answer